Is the deletion of that post a sign of better enforcement of quality standards?
Here is the post in question.
If the answer to my title is yes, I'd be glad to hear that, and I'll be the last one
being against better quality standards.
What infuriates me is that none of the anonymous downvoters gave a mathematical reason.
Both formulas are undoubtedly correct. The way this new contributor was treated must give
him the impression that this was not the case.

The post cannot be found when I click the link. Are you able to summarize the key points of the post you are talking about?

@RedFive The post is deleted, hence it is only visible to users with 10k+ reputations.

The question is a PSQ (and almost surely a duplicate too) so you should not have answered it (cf. EoQS). Some users cast non-mathematical downvotes in such circumstances (and likely they don't leave comments since doing so can result in arguments, retaliatory downvotes, etc).

Please put your question in the body of the post.  Don't just put the question in the title, and then the equivalent of "see title" in the body.  The body of a post should stand on its own.  The title is to give people an idea of what to expect from the post, it is not the first sentence of a post or a standalone statement of the question to be answered.

@ D.W. Someone deleted the comment where I summed up what was going on. I am getting tired of this. The take-away is that EoQS is more important than ever and I'll be the last one who is against that.

Please don't put clarifications or critical information in a comment.  Instead, [edit] your question so it reads well for someone who is seeing it for the first time and is self-contained.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand what is being asked.  Comments are designed to be used to request clarification, suggest improvements, or for transient information that can be deleted at any time.

I have had a few of my answers deleted [along with the parent question]. What happened, I had answered the question because I found the question in and of itself interesting and figuring it out was rewarding, even if the OP asking did not motivate the question i.e., there wasn't enough context. The thing is though, the rest of the board did not agree on the quality of the question and [in most instances] I can see why, due to the lack of context. It's unfortunate for me that an answer I was proud of got deleted along with the parent question, but it's just the way the cookie crumbles.
What's even more, in the above instances the question was borderline quality-wise [instead of clearly low-quality]. The votes-to-close and downvotes often were slower to come, when I answered the question had a net positive vote-count. But that still doesn't mean the deletion was a travesty of justice.
In any event, the question that was the subject of this thread is clearly low-quality and it looks like the downvotes arrived pretty quickly. If we encourage more of these types of questions--and if we reward the users who ask these questions, then MSE will end up becoming [even more of than it is already?] a homework-mill, something a lot of us do NOT want to see happening. So close and delete seems to me to be the appropriate remedy. Surely you could see that it--the question--was on its way out quickly?
A possible remedy--if you really feel that the question itself is interesting--may be to re-ask this question--giving credit to the original author while saying why this question is interesting and why we should care i.e., the context thing--and then giving your proof as an answer.

[Edit:  correction: I closed the question (via the 4th vote), but it was the OP who deleted it].
I deleted the answer (and, subsequently, the question) because the question did not meet quality standards, there were downvotes on both, and, prior to my deleting it, it seemed inevitable that the question would be deleted by other users anyway.
So, yes, it was EoQS.

Do you consult at all with the more experienced moderators? They might tell you that who moderates least, moderates best; if it seems inevitable that a question will be deleted by a vote of users, then let a vote of users delete it. What's the rush?

Actually, it appears, from the timeline, that you didn't delete the question. The user who posted the question deleted it. (But you did delete two answers.)

I am willing to take a less active role in this regard, @GerryMyerson.  This is the first time I can recall doing something like that.  There's no rush.  Also, yes, I deleted the answers first - I said so above in fact.

Sorry, yes, I misremembered: I closed it.

So is deletion of answers to PSQs even before the question itself gets deleted new policy now? Or why did that happen in this specific case?

No, @MaoWao; you don't need to worry about that: this was an isolated incident.

There have been more answers deleted this way.

There were existing down- and delete votes.  I still participate in the site, @ТymaGaidash.

However, the answer cannot be undeleted by regular users
